# Converting to DateTime error

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a cell on a DataGridView where I write an hour in this format(hh:mm), but when I try to convert that to a DateTime value it gives me this(01-01-001 00:00:00). Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
DateTime hora;
hora = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value);
```

Comment: What is the exact string/data in `dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value`?

Comment: I tried this one 11:23 for example.

Answer (score 1):

You likely need to use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with the appropriate format specifier.

Note that the date portion of the resulting `DateTime` will not get set if you use hours/minutes as your format, and will most likely be something you should ignore.

If the hours and minutes just represent a span of time, consider `TimeSpan` instead of `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

11:23 is not a valid `DateTime`, it does not have a Year, Month, and Day as well, That is a `TimeSpan`. Use the following:

```
TimeSpan thetime;
TimeSpan.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value, out thetime);
```